# Change twig inheritance tree from event listener

Tags: symfony, inheritance, twig

Following the [example from the Symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance.), I have a three-level twig inheritance:

```
app/Resources/views/base.html.twig
blog/layout.html.twig
blog/index.html.twig
```

Whenever an X-fancyBox header is present in the request, I would like to omit the top node of the tree (base.html.twig).

1. Is there any way of changing the inheritance tree from within an event handler?
2. In which event can this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the section [Making a layout conditional](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#making-a-layout-conditional) in the twig docs, I came up with the following solution.

```
{# app/Resources/views/blog/layout.html.twig #}

{% extends app.request.headers.has('X-fancyBox') ? 'base_fancybox.html.twig' : 'base.html.twig' %}
```

Still wondering whether there might be a more elegant solution.